# Use the same random Typoscript IMG_RESOURCE several times

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

How can I use the same random Image several times?
With the following Typoscript I've got different Images in different sizes.

```
lib.headerimage = COA_INT
lib.headerimage {
  1 = IMG_RESOURCE
  1 {
    file {
      import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
      treatIdAsReference = 1
      import.listNum = rand   
    }
  }
}

lib.headerimageSmall =< lib.headerimage
lib.headerimageSmall.1.file.width = 768

lib.headerimageTab =< lib.headerimageSmall
lib.headerimageTab.1.file.width = 1280

lib.headerimageDesktop =< lib.headerimageTab
lib.headerimageDesktop.1.file.width = 1920

lib.headerimageHigh =< lib.headerimageDesktop
lib.headerimageHigh.1.file.width = 2880
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a register for your image.
This might only work if you use fluidvariables instead of lib-TS

**as idea (not tested):**

```
page {
  1 = STORE_REGISTER
  1 {
    randomImage.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
    randomImage.cObject {
        file {
        import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        treatIdAsReference = 1
        import.listNum = rand   
    }


  10 = FLUID_TEMPLATE
  10 {
     name = ... 
     :
     variables {

         headerimageSmall = IMG_RESOURCE
         headerimageSmall {
             file.cObject = TEXT
             file.cobject.data = register:randomImage
             file.width = 768
         }

         headerimageTab < .headerimageSmall
         headerimageTab.file.width = 1280

         headerimageDesktop < lib.headerimageSmall
         headerimageDesktop.file.width = 1920

         headerimageHigh < lib.headerimageSmall
         headerimageHigh.file.width = 2880

     }
  }
}
```

maybe you could use the file-id as register, maybe the rendering for the fluid-variabels needs some adjustements.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to generate one random image and then resize it with fluid. Something like that:

```
<f:image src="{headerimageHigh}" width="2880" alt="high" />
<f:image src="{headerimageHigh}" width="1920" alt="desktop" />
<f:image src="{headerimageHigh}" width="1280" alt="tab" />
<f:image src="{headerimageHigh}" width="768" alt="small" />
```